# Execute Jquery For Each Instance

Tags: javascript

In a Blogger template, I am taking the img src of the featured image and applying it as a inline style background image to a div. That part works. The problem is I can't seem to figure out how to do it for each instance.

This is what I came up with so far looking at other examples:

```js
// Let's make the featured image a background image
$('.post.hentry').each(function() {
  var getImageSrc = $('.post-featured-image.image-element').attr('src');
  $('.post-featured-image.custom-post-image').css('background-image', 'url(' + getImageSrc + ')');
});
```

This doesn't work as it takes the featured image of the first instance, and applies it to all other instances. How do I make it work properly for each instance.

A simple markup of the HTML structure looks like this:

```
<div class="blog-posts">
 <article>
  <div class="post-outer">
   <div class="post hentry">
    <div class="post-featured-image custom-post-image"></div>
    <img class="post-featured-image image-element" src="image-1.jpg" />
     body text
   </div>
  </div>
 </article>
 <article>
  <div class="post-outer">
   <div class="post hentry">
    <div class="post-featured-image custom-post-image"></div>
    <img class="post-featured-image image-element" src="image-2.jpg" />
     body text
   </div>
  </div>
 </article>
 <article>
  <div class="post-outer">
   <div class="post hentry">
    <div class="post-featured-image custom-post-image"></div>
    <img class="post-featured-image image-element" src="image-3.jpg" />
     body text
   </div>
  </div>
 </article>
</div>
```

In other words, looking at the markup, I need each img src(.image-element) to be applied as the background image of the previous element(.custom-post-image) for each instance.

Comment: Can you post the HTML? Hard to say without seeing what exactly you're trying to select in the DOM

Comment: I guess you´re trying to get the '.post-featured-image.image-element' inside the ''.post.hentry'' but when you call $('.post-featured-image.image-element') you´re actually getting all of the elements in the DOM that have that class. Maybe check the .children() function https://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: Posted simplified HTML markup.

Comment: You're missing a bunch of `</div>` end tags at the moment, is that really your HTML? I'd be surprised if it works, if that's really what it is

Comment: @CertainPerformance forgot to self close the .custom-featured-image div. Does it make sense now?

Comment: You have opening `<div>`s right before the end of the articles `</article>`? Need another `</div>` at least (or is that a typo for `</div>`?)

Comment: @CertainPerformance typo, fixed.

Comment: @OmarYafer I tried your code and experimented with it, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @Xarcell, sorry about that, havent used jquery for a long time. Check my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the inner img and then [first()](https://api.jquery.com/first/) to select only the first element.

```js
// Let's make the featured image a background image
$('.post.hentry').each(function() {
  //Get the first element of the image elements inside get post hentry
  let getImageSrc = $(this).find('.image-element').first().attr('src');
  console.log(getImageSrc);
  //THe rest of your code here
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blog-posts">
  <article>
    <div class="post-outer">
      <div class="post hentry">
        <div class="post-featured-image custom-post-image">
          <img class="post-featured-image image-element" src="i_am_1" /> body text
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="post-outer">
      <div class="post hentry">
        <div class="post-featured-image custom-post-image">
          <img class="post-featured-image image-element" src="i_am_2" /> body text
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="post-outer">
      <div class="post hentry">
        <div class="post-featured-image custom-post-image">
          <img class="post-featured-image image-element" src="i_am_3" /> body text
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

EDIT

---

For further clarification

Doing `$('.of-a-class')` would return an array of 0~n elements, hence the need to use the `.first()` function. As I commented earlier when you used `$('.image-element')` you brought all the elements of that class that belong to the DOM, not those that belong to `.post.hentry`. Thats why you need to use `.find()`, to get the `.image-element` elements that belong to `.post.hentry`

Comment: This did the opposite of the problem. Instead of applying the first featured image to all instances, it took the last featured image and applied it to all instances. I need it to apply each featured image within each instance.

Comment: The same logic applies to  $('.post-featured-image.custom-post-image'). You have to get the elements that belong to .post.hentry. You´re probably getting the last featured instance because it´s the last one on the cycle

Comment: something along the lines of $(this).find('.post-featured-image.custom-post-image').first().css(...);

Comment: There is only one element with the class .image-element within each instance. So I don't understand the need for first().

Comment: @Xarcell you logically know this, but the interpreter might not. first() is to ensure that you´re working with a single element. It might not be necessary if you can always ensure there will only be one element of that class.

Comment: this is a working example https://jsfiddle.net/nyctqj74/2/, but before you look at it you should first research about the DOM and how it is built.

Comment: Ok, I used your code from the working example and it works. I could have swore that is what I already used and it didn't work. Maybe I did another typo, I dunno. Anyway, thank you for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not passing the corresponding indices.
There may be a better way to do it if you show the html structure. but the below code should work, assuming there are equal number of both classes and are together

```
// Let's make the featured image a background image
$('.post.hentry').each(function(index) { //get the corresponding index
  var getImageSrc = $('.post-featured-image.image-element').get(index).getAttribute('src'); //retrieve src of the image at corresponding index
  $('.post-featured-image.custom-post-image').get(index).style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + getImageSrc + ')');
});
```

or with only Jquery

```
$('.post.hentry').each(function(idx) {
  var getImageSrc = $('.post-featured-image.image-element').index(idx).attr('src');
  $('.post-featured-image.custom-post-image').index(idx).css('background-image', 'url(' + getImageSrc + ')');
});
```

Comment: This did not work. I added simplified HTML markup to the original post if that helps.